# Erro ao integrar o Waze ao site PHP?

Tags: php, api, aplicação-web, maps, google-maps-api-3

Tenho um site php e preciso carregar um mapa e dados do waze. Como posso fazer isso ?

Estou usando esse repositório: https://github.com/Nimrod007/waze-api

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se você já está utilizando uma API, qual é o problema?

Comment: Carregar o mapa ? Ele não aparece !!

Comment: Com realizar a integração do waze com o site php ???

Comment: Sua pergunta não está fazendo sentido algum. Por favor, [edit] e ser mais claro sobre o que pretende fazer. Uma API, por definição, serve para integrar um serviço à uma aplicação e você já está utilizando uma, como dito na pergunta, então qual é o problema? Novamente, ênfase em [edit].

Comment: como integrar site php ao waze ?

Comment: O que estão querendo dizer é pra você [edit] a pergunta e mostrar como já tentou usar a API. Afinal você disse que está usando ela.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver este problema usando um iframe no qual inserir o mapa do api do Waze:

```
<div id="exibirMapa" class="exibirMapa">

<iframe src="https://embed.waze.com/iframe?zoom=12&lat=32.10911&lon=34.81773" width="700" height="500"></iframe>

</div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Url para documentação do [Waze](https://support.google.com/waze/partners/answer/6287370?hl=pt-BR)